# How to automatically delete rows that contain a date with more than 3 days offset to the past from now?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, delete-row

I am trying to get a script going that will automatically delete rows with a date over 3 days old (4 days on)

I found this script that I was hoping to be able to adapt:

```
function DeleteOldEntries() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //give your sheet name below instead of Sheet1
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Foglio1");

  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();


  var currentDate = new Date();
  var oneweekago = new Date();
  oneweekago.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 7);

  for (i = lastrow; i >= 2; i--) {
    var tempdate = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();

    if (tempdate < oneweekago) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}
```

But there seems to be an error in the script itself that I need to figure out before adapting it to 4 days instead of 7 (that part is easy)

My sheet has 3 columns with the date in column C if that info is helpful

Answer (score 3):

***"date in column C, if that info is helpful"***

It is indeed ! instead of trying to get a date in column A as it it done in this line :

```
var tempdate = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
```

you should look at the value in column C like this :

```
var tempdate = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
```

but to be more efficient you should do these comparisons at array level, try it like below and it will run much faster ...

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Foglio1");
var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array

var currentDate = new Date();
var oneweekago = new Date();
oneweekago.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 7);

for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
var tempdate = values[i-1][2];// arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col3 = [2]

if(tempdate < oneweekago)  
{
  sheet.deleteRow(i);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be much much faster if your rows are in order of date, newest at the top and you delete all the rows at once and not one at a time.

```
function deleteOldData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CallHub1");
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
  var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array

  var currentDate = new Date();
  var daysago = new Date().setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 3);
  var yearago = new Date().setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 365);


  for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
    var tempdate = values[i-1][0];// arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col3 = [2]
    if(tempdate < daysago)  {
      if(tempdate < yearago)  {continue;}
      sheet.deleteRows(1, i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```