# Google Sheets - Delete Expired Rows Based On Date part 2

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have issues with deleting rows based on date automatically. I've tried suggestions given on this link ([Google Sheets - Delete Expired Rows Based On Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114435/google-sheets-delete-expired-rows-based-on-date)) but it's just removing all my entries leaving only my header

I wanted to remove the rows once the date (on column B) is expired by current date without removing new entries with new dates too

This is the code that i used based on that link:

```
function DeleteOldEntries() {
    activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var datarange = activeSheet.getDataRange();
    var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
    var values = datarange.getValues();

    var currentDate = new Date();

    for (i = lastrow; i >= 2; i--) {
        var tempDate = values[i - 1][1];
        if ((tempDate != NaN) && (tempDate <= currentDate)) {
            activeSheet.deleteRow(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Any modifications on this code will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you check what are values of tempDate and currentDate for every iteration?

Comment: based on the link above i think the current date taken based on system while the tempdate is taken from column B in my spreadsheet

Comment: Log these variables and check values. Then you have more understanding why condition (if ((tempDate != NaN) && (tempDate <= currentDate))) is always getting true

Comment: is there any way to do so? as this is my first experience on using javascript

Comment: @AlbertTanuwijaya How are you going with your Google Sheets problem? Have you solved it, or are you still looking for help?