# Google Sheets - Script to delete rows where form response starts with a space

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, delete-row, spam, spam-prevention

Basically, I have a Google Form  that feeds into a Google Sheet, and I want to filter out all the responses that start with a space (which are spam). I have a second sheet in the file that filters out all the spam rows in the `Responses` sheet such that this `Clean` sheet has only the desired rows. This works perfectly, but the issue is that there are so many thousands of spam responses that it takes a while a while for this `Clean` sheet to load. So, I would occasionally like to run a script (I assume it can't automatically run itself, but let me know if that is possible) to delete all the spam rows in order to make everything load faster.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649223/google-sheets-script-to-delete-date-expired-rows) question where the answer gives a script that deletes rows that are older than one week. I was hoping that somebody could write one like this that deletes rows where the response starts with a space. Or, if somebody has a better solution for my entire workflow, I am open to that, too.

Answer (score 0):

function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var resp=e.values.shift();//remove timestamp
  for(var i=0;i

I used an installable trigger for my testing

[onFormSubmit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: When I try to run this, it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 1, file "Test")`. Am I doing something wrong or is there an issue with the code?